Plasmo Extension Chrome - How can I create an API?
I am currently coding a Chrome Extension using Plasmo.
What i want is to setup Stripe within it, to add a subscription to my extension.
I was able to make queries to stripe using what was explained on the website :
Quickstart with Stripe
But what i don't understand, is what to put inside :
PLASMO_PUBLIC_API_URI=http://localhost:8472/

when it will be in production.
Do you have any idea ?
I won't have a server on vercel, so what should i use instead of the localhost server ?
I think i don't really understand the concept of server within the extension, and why i need to make like real requests inside the Extension.

You need a server in order to make the calls to the Stripe API from a safe environment. Trying to communicate with Stripe from the code of the extension (which is available to the users) would expose your Stripe secrets.
